# ExactTarget Python FuelSDK Create DataExtension with Default Value for Date as 'Use Current Date'

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

I create most of my DataExtensions by API call, as the vast majority of them contain the same layout.  Unfortunately, I've not found a way to replicate the UI's ability to add a default value of the date/time the data row was inserted into the data extension.

[image: Date Default Value]
This is easy to do via the UI, but when you create dozens of Data Extensions per day, all via API, it would be nice not to have to manually touch each of them in the UI.

Please help me solve for this use case.

--- Answer ---

[image: Result from API]
This image shows the text as 'getdate()' which turns out to be valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `GetDate()` as the default value.  There's an example on [**this**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm) SFMC wiki page.

```
<Field>
  <Name>Date_type</Name>
  <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
  <DefaultValue>getdate()</DefaultValue>
  <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
</Field>
```

Comment: I had tried this, but dismissed it as the result didn't look right in the UI.  Actually though, it does work.  Thanks!

Comment: The link has moved - this content is now at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm